# How to break inner loop and next for outer loop in ruby?

Tags: ruby, loops, break

I dont want to use `if` statement.

```
count = 0 
10.times do |i|
  all = (i..20).collect{ |ii| ii < rand(30) || break }
  count+=1 if all # i dont want to use `if` statement 
end

p count
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got something in the similar matter:

```
count = 0 
10.times do |i|
   (i..20).collect{ |ii| ii < rand(30) || break } || next
   count += 1
end
```

So it is just boolean algebra. `if` condition is taken place, when `all`, i.e. result of `collect` method, isn't `nil`, so we need to `next` keyword worked, when result of `collect` is `nil`. Therefore we just set `or` operator between `collect` and `next`, in order to `next` is occuring when result of `collect` is `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

```
count = (0..9).count { |i| (i..20).all?{ |j| j < rand(30) } }
```

Comment: nice, but i asked another question.

anyway thanks +1

Comment: Fair enough - just in case it was useful..